# model = User in Meta class of django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to read a code that concerns about user registration form. The code has a Meta class which I know what it does, but assigning model to User doesn't give sense to me. Can you please explain it?

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User # explain?
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? It's just saying that User is the  model this ModelForm is based on.

Comment: `UserCreationForm` is a subclass of `ModelForm` class, and ModelForm require a model to work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django relies on [Inner Classes](https://pythonspot.com/inner-classes/) to provide metadata, Your `UserRegisterForm` needs to know when you call `UserRegisterForm.save()` what database table to send this form data to.

This is why you need `model = User` inside your `Meta` class, so the form knows where to go about storing.